# Strange multiple definition error

Tags: c++, multiple-definition-error

```
vio@!@#$:~/cpp/OOP/6$ g++ -o main main.o NormalAccount.o HighCreditAccount.o Account.o AccountHandler.o
AccountHandler.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `AccountHandler::account_number'
main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I got the error message above.
But I couldn't find the code where it is multiply defined, so I changed all account_number to number_of_account in 'account.h' and 'AccountHandler.cpp'
and

```
vio@!@#$:~/cpp/OOP/6$ vi AccountHandler.cpp 
vio@!@#$:~/cpp/OOP/6$ g++ -c AccountHandler.cpp 
vio@!@#$:~/cpp/OOP/6$ g++ -o main main.o NormalAccount.o HighCreditAccount.o Account.o AccountHandler.o
vio@!@#$:~/cpp/OOP/6$
```

it compiled well.

After that, I changed main.cpp a little

```
vio@!@#$:~/cpp/OOP/6$ g++ -c main.cpp
vio@!@#$:~/cpp/OOP/6$ g++ -o main main.o NormalAccount.o HighCreditAccount.o Account.o AccountHandler.o
AccountHandler.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `AccountHandler::number_of_account'
main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and error message emerged again.

I used #ifndef #define #define in all header file and
when I changed the variable in AccountHandler.cpp and accounthandler.h, it compiled well again,
so I wonder why it happens

Here is the code:

```
#ifndef __ACCOUNTHANDLER_H__
#define __ACCOUNTHANDLER_H__

#include "account.h"

class AccountHandler
{
private:
    Account* account[100];
    static int number_of_account;
public:
    AccountHandler(){}

    void show_menu();
    void make_account();
    void deposit_money();
    void withdraw_money();
    void show_all_account_info();

    ~AccountHandler();
};

int AccountHandler::number_of_account=0;

#endif
```

Comment: What is `AccountHandler::account_number` (or `AccountHandler::number_of_account`)? How do you declare it? How do you define it? And most importantly, _where_ do you define it? You need to show us some code, or it will be almost impossible to answer this question without guessing.

Comment: Header guards only prevent multiple inclusion (and thus multiple definitions) inside a single translation unit. If you define a global object in a header, you'll get a definition of it in every translation unit (cpp) where you include that header (breaking One Definition Rule with it). You can either define the object with internal linkage (`static`) or just declare it as `extern` and define in exactly one translation unit.

Comment: @jrok: Since it appears to be a static class member, you can't give it internal linkage, or use `extern` in the declaration. If it were at namespace scope, then giving it internal linkage is almost certainly the wrong thing to do, since you'll get a separate copy in each translation unit; that would be confusing, to say the least.

Comment: Perhaps you could show us where and how the variable is declared and defined. Without that information, answering the question involves a certain amount of guesswork.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Ah yes, I ignored the fact that it's a class member. Well, those do have external linkage by default. I agree that internal linkage is most likely not what OP wants.

Comment: OK, I've reformatted the code so we can read it. As you can see, the variable is defined at the end of the header. Move that definition into a source file.

Comment: I really appreciate it. It's my first time in stackoverflow, and I really like it. Thank u again for answering my question

Comment: @user2323357: No worries. When you post code in a question, it needs to be indented by 4 spaces to be properly formatted; you can do that automatically by selecting the code and pressing the `{}` button.

Comment: This is not the problem, but names that contain two underscores (`__ACCOUNTHANDLER_H__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define something in a header, then it will be defined in every translation unit that includes that header - in your case, both `AccountHandler` and `main`. You should *declare* it in a header (if it needs to be accessed from multiple units), and *define* it in just one source file.

Assuming that it's a static class member (I'm having to guess, since you forgot to show us the code), you want something like:

```
// header
class AccountHandler 
{
public:
    static size_t number_of_account; // declaration

    // other members...
};

// source file
size_t AccountHandler::number_of_account; // definition
```

Presumably, in your code, that definition is in the header.

That's assuming it's supposed to be static at all; that it's independent of any particular account (e.g. it represents the number of accounts that exist), rather than being associated with each account (e.g. it represents an account number). If it's not supposed to be static, then make sure it's not declared `static`.

Include guards won't help with this; they prevent the header from being included more than once in each translation unit, but still allow them to be included from multiple units.

Comment: i can understand but then how can I solve this?
I need to use AccountHandler class in main, and it declared in accounthandler.h, and defined in AccountHandler.cpp.
Should i combine accounthandler.h and AccountHandler.cpp?
And, why is it compiled well just after edited AccountHandler.cpp and accounthandler.h?

Comment: @user2323357: It certainly looks like its defined in a header. But without seeing your code I can't be sure; it's just your word against the compiler's. Have a thorough look in all the headers to make sure it really isn't defined in any of them.

Comment: @user2323357: "Should i combine accounthandler.h and AccountHandler.cpp?" Almost certainly not. Just make sure your headers contain only declarations, not definitions, of variables.

Comment: @user2323357: Thanks for posting the code. My guess was correct - the variable is defined at the end of the header, and that definition wants to be in a single source file instead.

Comment: I think definition should be like "size_t AccountHandler::number_of_account;" exclude 'static'
if i correct, plz edit the code above

Comment: @user2323357: Yes, you're quite right; the `static` only goes on the declaration.