# C++, multiple definition

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I need to define a constant containing an environment variable (Linux, g++). I would prefer to use `string`, but `std::getenv` needs `*char` (this is not yet my question). To avoid the *multiple definition* error I used the `define` workaround, but it is not enough.  The program is simple: `DataLocation.hpp`

```
#ifndef HEADER_DATALOCATION_H
#define HEADER_DATALOCATION_H

#include <string>

using namespace std;

const char* ENV_APPL_ROOT = "APPL_ROOT";

[...]

#endif
```

And `DataLocation.cpp`:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "DataLocation.hpp"

using namespace std;

// Private members
DataLocation::DataLocation()
{
  rootLocation = std::getenv(ENV_APPL_ROOT);
}

[...]
```

And a test programm, `Test.cpp`

```
#include "DataLocation.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  DataLocation *dl;
  dl = DataLocation::getInstance();
  auto s = dl->getRootLocation();

  cout << "Root: " << s << "\n";
}
```

But compiling, I get the following error:

```
/tmp/ccxX0RFN.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `ENV_APPL_ROOT'
DataLocation.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Test] Error 1
```

In my code there is no second definition, and I protect the header from being called twice. What is wrong?

The typical answers to the *multiple definition* question are either

- to separate declaration / implementation
- the multiple include

Is there a way to separate declaration and implementation in my case?

**Edit 1**

This question is not linked to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234231/strange-multiple-definition-error) because mine refers to a constant. In the solution of the cited question I do not see how to solve my problem.

Comment: It is defined twice -- once in each of the .cpp files that you included the .hpp file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange multiple definition error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234231/strange-multiple-definition-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are including the header twice.  Once from DataLocation.cpp (where it finds `HEADER_DATALOCATION_H` not yet defined and thus defines `ENV_APPL_ROOT`), and once from Test.cpp (where it agains finds `HEADER_DATALOCATION_H` not yet defined and thus defines `ENV_APPL_ROOT` again.)  The "header protection" only protects a header file being included multiple times *in the same compilation unit*.

You need:

```
extern const char* ENV_APPL_ROOT;
```

in the header file, and

```
const char* ENV_APPL_ROOT = "APPL_ROOT";
```

in one .cpp file.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
extern const char* ENV_APPL_ROOT;
```

in the header file, and place

```
const char* ENV_APPL_ROOT = "APPL_ROOT";
```

in **one particular** translation unit (e.g. `DataLocation.cpp`).

This should fix it.